# How do I create a SSB for Outlook web mail using Fluid?

Tags: web-browser, websites, url, web-app, fluid.app

Has anyone successfully created a fluid app for outlook web mail (aka live mail)?  I've tried but either the site opens in my web browser or (after white listing variations of the site url) I get an error message stating that I need to use internet explorer or an updated version of safari.  The site opens fine in my firefox web browser (my default browser) so I don't think it's a browser problem.

Comment: Developer of Fluid here. Please see my previous answer with [full details on how the "whitelist" feature works in Fluid](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52200/fluid-when-i-try-to-login-my-fluid-app-launches-the-default-browser-instead/52201#52201).

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Single Site Browser (SSB) with Fluid, by default it only allows you to access specific URLs within it. The allowed URLs are by default (in this example): `*outlook.com*`.

What you need to do is open the SSB, enter it's preferences, choose the 'Whitelist' section, and add `*live.com*` to the whitelist. This should allow you to access both the login page, and actual Live Mail interface without issue.

If pages continue to open in your browser, take the URL and add it's domain to the whitelist.

Comment: I had added several variations of the mail.live.com url to the whitelist, but not *live.com*.  When I added that, it worked like a charm.  Thank you very much Jason for your help.

Comment: Well, I guess I spoke too soon.  It worked once but then went back to giving me the error message that I need to use internet explorer or an updated version of safari.  Still appreciate your help though.

Comment: You can probably change the User Agent Fluid sends to the site to something else. It's under the App name menu (left of the 'File' menu).

Answer (score -1):

I also needed to add *office.com* to my whitelist if people are still having problems... Or you can just flip it to "allow browsing to any URL".