# Fluid: Fluid links open using Fluid browser instead of my default browser (Chrome)

Tags: safari, google-chrome, fluid.app

I have created a couple of Fluid Apps to run Google Calendar and Gmail.

These work fine except that web links launched from them also launch in Fluid itself, rather than in my default browser, which is Chrome.

This is a problem as a lot of the G-Suite stuff doesn't work well in the fluid browser (e.g. google doc links give javascript errors).

How can I get my Fluid gmail app to open links in the system default browser rather than in the Fluid browser?

Comment: This is not a duplicate as i this case Chrome is the default browser whilst the other question was how to use a non default browser.

Comment: Not a duplicate as Mark points out. As noted I have already set my default browser; the question is why Fluid ignores it and opens Safari anyway. Please remove the duplicate markers.

Comment: Fluid isn't what you think it is.  Fluid isn't ignoring your default browser settings, a Fluid SSB *is* a browser.  Perhaps there's some tool that will wrap Chrome, but Fluid isn't it.

Comment: Very good point, of which I was not aware, and I have updated the question to reflect this. It's not Safari that Fluid is using for links, it's the Fluid browser itself. I am ok with Fluid running the original gmail in its own custom browser, but it would be super useful if I could get it to launch links using the default browser.

Comment: After the recent edits, I believe this question is now a duplicate of : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52200/fluid-when-i-try-to-login-my-fluid-app-launches-the-default-browser-instead/52201#52201

Comment: Actually I am getting the exact opposite problem. Fluid is *not* launching in my default browser whereas this question is complaining that it only launches in default browser (!). However some of the info in the answer re using whitelists may help and explain. Will take a look and see if I can fix based on that. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure this out?

My problem is this. I used Fluid for Mac to create a Gmail app (which is great.)

However, when I open links for other Google apps (gCal, GDocs, etc.) it opens in Fluid browser instead of my default browser.

I can't figure out how to whitelist Fluid to only show links that are Gmail and not get confused with all other "google.com" apps/websites. I hate to reask the same question... but I couldn't find the answer in this thread. Help!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/327993)